# If a women strictly follows the all rules of Islam but a task is assigned to her as deliver audio lecture on social media Is it permissible?

Tags: practical-islam, hijab

If a women wear veil during studies but if a task is assigned to her i.e: to upload audio lecture on social media then Is it permissible that she can deliver audio lecture on social media. and If it is not permissible then what can she do, if the task assigned is mandatory.

Comment: By audio lecture you mean that she will be speaking to an audience?

Comment: yes i mean that no on can seen her only can listen to her.

Comment: @fozia I do not understand the point. How is the veil (niqab) related to delivering an audio lecture? A podcast implies only the voice is transmitted. So her audience will be unaware of what she wears or does not wear. Please clarify.

Comment: Is Islam allow a women to record her voice and share it on social media.. everyone listen to her(Mahram as well as Na-Mahram)

Comment: Is Islam allow a women to record her voice and share it on social media.. In this case everyone can listen to her(Mahram as well as Na-Mahram).  She wears hijab and strictly follows the all rules of Islam even she doesn't speak with Na-Maharam. In this case what should she do??

Comment: can any one answer me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Giving audio lectures is not per se haram for women.
Many scholars consider the voice of a woman as 'awrah (based on verses such as [33:32](https://legacy.quran.com/33/32)), but none of them has ever rejected ahadith transmitted by female sahabah (including the mothers of belivers, for example 'Aisha used to give hadith lessons behind a screen) or female scholars (the wife of ibn Hajar al-'Asqalani was herself a hadith scholar who got a certification from al-Hafidh al-'Iraqi one of the teachers of ibn Hajar himself and she used to teach while he was alive), which shows that it is possible to teach others (even men) for women.

So basically giving an audio lesson or lecture is halal for women if they respect the sharia rules on mahrams, 'awrah etc.. For example some scholars add as a condition that the women should speak in a neutral voice to avoid fitnah which is derived from the linked verse.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can deliver your audio message without showing your face. There are lot of examples when a women came to S.A.W to ask any problem and knowing somethings from Prophet. And After the death of S.A.W the wives of S.A.W also deliver her knowledge as audio without showing her.

Comment: My question is about recorded lectures and the wives of prophet (S.A.W) only deliver an audio lectures and do not record their voices

Comment: Hi,  Medi1saif can you answer me please

Answer (score -2):

Indeed you can, Islam isn't that strict about women. You are free to do live audio, it is completely fine.